# Using external accessory framework to read all protocols

Tags: ios, iphone, external-accessory

I want to make an app that interfaces with a sony radio that has an app to control the unit. It uses external accessory framework from iPhone so how can i get all the protocols from the radio or is there anyway to read the protocols coming from the sony app that would communicate with the radio. In short can i get the protocols from the sony radio using external accessory framework?

Answer (score 0):

How does the device connect to the radio? 30 pin/lightning?  Bluetooth? or WiFi?

Only the manufacturer who has entered into the MFI license agreement with Apple will have the details on how to interface with their device via cable or Bluetooth, so it is unlikely that you will be able to discover the protocols without some fairly low-level electronic monitoring of the signals.

If it is a WiFi connection then you may be able decode the protocol using Wireshark or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this app to get the supported protocols: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html

But you won't be able to do much without reverse engineering the protocol.